# Split one column data based on searching string in the same column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, split

I have data in a cell contains below

```
(2
C111
EVT_STAT_CD2
N19
Scheduled2
O111
Unscheduled) one cell data not multiple rows.
```

I need to get data as below. As well numbers should be excluded.
If C then EVT_STAT_CD value,
 
If N then Scheduled value,
 
If O then Unscheduled value

I need this split in Oracle SQL or PLSQL

Please help for getting the above data/details

Comment: Please have a look at [mcve] to improve your question. What is the structure of you input data? Is this s single value that contains a multi-row string? Different columns? Different rows ? Also, please post the exact needed result for that input data

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be the answer you're looking for:

```
SELECT CASE tbl.[your_value]
            WHEN 'C' THEN tbl.EVT_STAT_CD
            WHEN 'N' THEN tbl.Scheduled
            WHEN 'O' THEN tbl.Unscheduled
FROM [your_table] AS tbl
```

Comment: EVT_STAT_CD,Scheduled,Unscheduled are not constant values. there may be a change in value length. The data provided is a sample. Thanks for your response.